# What is the difference between ∞ and ♾️?

Tags: character, unicode

What is the difference between ∞ and ♾️? Both are described as *infinity* in MacOS character viewer, though in the first case it is *INFINITY* and in the second case *infinity*

Comment: I think the blue one is a colour emoji "forever" symbol.  On this page when I inspect it, it says it's a Segoe UI Emoji. I'm using Windows though. Might be different on a Mac.  The first one (in black) is just the regular infinity glyph from a regular font.

Comment: You can see it here [in this screenshot](https://imgur.com/5jKHQwm) when I inspect it.

Comment: @BillyKerr One is blue for your? For me they are both black.

Comment: Yes it's a blue emoji for me.  [This one here](https://emojipedia.org/infinity). But I'm on Win 11. No idea what a Mac will show.

Comment: @BillyKerr What inspector "mode" are you in on your screen shot? I'm on Firefox and can't find your view. How did you get there?

Comment: In firefox, select the character, then right click it, and choose Inspect, select the Fonts panel on the right.

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't find anything font-related when I do that? Can you elaborate? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first is Infinity, the second is actually the '**permanent paper sign**'.

If you search in the Character viewer, then the initial result says 'infinity' but if you then open up the unicode, the name changes [who knows why] & you see it's grouped with other recycling symbols. Also note it's not truly continuous like infinity, it's more of a möbius strip.

[image]

'True' infinity, on the other hand, is grouped with other mathematical symbols.

[image]

On Mac, rather than try to inspect it in a browser, copy/paste it into the Character Viewer
[I think the default key command is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[Space]</kbd>  ]

[Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/infinity) (yes, really;) explains the possible confusion.

> The symbol for infinity enclosed within a circle or square.
> Originally encoded as a symbol to represent acid-free paper, this permanent paper sign was later given emoji presentation to form an infinity emoji.
> May also be used by members of the autism rights movement to represent neurodiversity.
> Infinity was approved as part of Unicode 4.1 in 2005 under the name "Permanent Paper Sign" and added to Emoji 11.0 in 2018.

I noticed most of the font variations do have it in a circle.

[image]